# Compare-Object Delete File if file does not exist on source

Tags: powershell

I have this PowerShell code that compares 2 directories and removes files if the files no longer exist in the source directory.

For example say I have Folder 1 & Folder 2. I want to compare Folder 1 with Folder 2, If a file doesn't exist anymore in Folder 1 it will remove it from Folder 2.

this code works ok but I have a problem where it also picks up file differences on the date/time. I only want it to pick up a difference if the file doesn't exist anymore in Folder 1.

```
  Compare-Object $source $destination -Property Name  -PassThru | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | % {
        if(-not $_.FullName.PSIsContainer) {
            UPDATE-LOG  "File: $($_.FullName) has been removed from source"
            Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
    }
```

Is there an extra Where-Object {$file1 <> $file2} or something like that.?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are getting the information for `$source` and `$destination` I am assuming you are using `Get-ChildItem`

What i would do to eliminate the issue with date/time would be to not capture it in these variables. For Example:

```
$source = Get-ChildItem C:\temp\Folder1 -Recurse | select -ExpandProperty FullName
$destination = Get-ChildItem C:\temp\Folder2 -Recurse | select -ExpandProperty FullName
```

By doing this you only get the `FullName` Property for each object that is a child item not the date/time.

You would need to change some of the script after doing this for it to still work.

Comment: Yes this is the code that I am using  

    $source = Get-ChildItem  $pathofSourceFiles -Recurse | Exclude-Directories $excludedDirectories
    $destination = Get-ChildItem $pathofDestination -Recurse | Exclude-Directories $excludedDirectoriessing to get the information:

Comment: But like I mentioned before, this code works fine on files that have the same name yet the date/time is different but not so when a Folder..

Answer (score 0):

The following script can serve your purpose

```
$Item1=Get-ChildItem 'SourcePath'
$Item2=Get-ChildItem 'DestinationPath'

$DifferenceItem=Compare-Object  $Item1 $Item2  

$ItemToBeDeleted=$DifferenceItem | where {$_.SideIndicator -eq  "=>" }



foreach ($item in $ItemToBeDeleted)
{
    $FullPath=$item.InputObject.FullName

    Remove-Item $FullPath -Force
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is basically what I have got just refacted alittle.

Comment: the above code does the work what you have asked for

Answer (score 0):

If I am not getting it wrong, the issue is your code is deleting the file with different time-stamp as compared to source:
 Did you try -ExcludeProperty?

```
    $source = Get-ChildItem "E:\New folder" -Recurse | select -ExcludeProperty Date
```

Comment: The information on Compare-Object  -Property is according to MSDN

Specifies an array of properties of the reference and difference objects to compare.

If my only -Property is Name why does it care about the date/time at all. LIke I said before, it works perfectly fine for files, but if 2 folders have a different date but the same name it picks up a difference

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

In PowerShell V5:

```
 $yourdir1="c:\temp"
 $yourdir2="c:\temp2"

 $filesnamedir1=(gci $yourdir1 -file).Name
 gci $yourdir2 -file | where Name -notin $filesnamedir1| remove-item
```

In old PowerShell:

```
 $yourdir1="c:\temp"
 $yourdir2="c:\temp2"

 $filesnamedir1=(gci $yourdir1 | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $false}).Name
 gci $yourdir2 | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $false -and $_.Name -notin $filesnamedir1} | remove-item
```

If you want to compare files in multiple dir, use the -recurse option for every gci command.